# the new line character is not working for my program?

Tags: python

How do I get this output using one line of code and the \n character? btw, I am using Python only.

"I'm"

""learning""

"""Python"""

Comment: Why new line character is not working? show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seperator.

```
print('"I\'m"','""learning""','"""python"""',sep='\n')
```

Comment: This does not match the desired output containing literal double-quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Strings can be enclosed either in single-quotes or double-quotes.  If you enclose in single-quotes, then the string itself can contain double-quotes without special handling (i.e. escaping with backslashes), and vice-versa.

Since your desired output has mostly double-quotes, it is easiest to use single-quotes to enclose the string, with one backslash to escape the apostrophe in `I'm`:

```
print('"I\'m"\n""learning""\n"""Python"""')
```